# Selecting the most specific row match based on multiple potential column values

Tags: sql-server

I have a bit of a convoluted situation and I'm hoping someone here might be able to offer some insight.

I have a series of tables that list certain criteria that are configurable by our clients. These criteria, when taken together, are used to determine which settings are needed to process certain data for them. Because the nature of the system requires it to be very dynamic, I've come up with a loose organization of "scopes" that combine to form a single "stack". A given client can have multiple stacks configured, and we use the best possible matching stack to choose which settings to apply to processing their data.

I can - for lack of a better term - brute-force the selection to determine which stack to use, however I'm sure there's a more elegant and maintainable solution. Any advice would be appreciated. In particular, a better way of ranking them besides just the total number of applicable rows.

See below for a sample schema that represents the data.

TLDR:
 * There are various ScopeTypes which represent potential types of criteria to be used
 * A given Scope references a corresponding ScopeType and value, acting as a single criteria
 * *Scopes are configured by us, not the user*
 * A stack is a collection of scopes (correlated via the StacksScopesMap table) and *is configurable by the user*
 * A given user can have an arbitrarily large number of stacks with any combination of scopes
 * *Not all scopes are required when defining a Stack* 
 * *Not all scopes are necessarily applicable when selecting a Stack* 
 * A stack can reference any number of scopes based on type, but only a single scope of each type - i.e.: a Stack can not reference two scopes of type ClientId

**Update:**  I revised the query I'm using significantly, however I would still love to know if there's a better way to accomplish this. Of particular concern would be the method used to weight the results to determine the final Stack selection, and whether there's any holes in my logic that might come back and bite me in the ass later.

I'm also not opposed to changing the schema if there is a better way to organize this.

Thanks!

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01c739/6)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE [ScopeTypes](
  [ScopeTypeId] [tinyint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [Deactivated] [datetime] NULL,
  [Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ScopeTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [ScopeTypeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [Scopes](
  [ScopeId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [ScopeTypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
  [Scope] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [Deactivated] [datetime] NULL,
  [Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Scopes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [ScopeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [Stacks](
  [StackId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [Deactivated] [datetime] NULL,
  [Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Stacks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [StackId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [StacksScopesMap](
  [StackScopeMapId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [StackId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [ScopeId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StacksScopesMap] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [StackId] ASC,
  [ScopeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [Scopes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Scopes_ScopeTypes] FOREIGN KEY([ScopeTypeId])
REFERENCES [ScopeTypes] ([ScopeTypeId])

ALTER TABLE [Scopes] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Scopes_ScopeTypes]

ALTER TABLE [StacksScopesMap]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Scopes_Stacks] FOREIGN KEY([ScopeId])
REFERENCES [Scopes] ([ScopeId])

ALTER TABLE [StacksScopesMap] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Scopes_Stacks]

ALTER TABLE [StacksScopesMap]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Stacks_Scopes] FOREIGN KEY([StackId])
REFERENCES [Stacks] ([StackId])

ALTER TABLE [StacksScopesMap] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Stacks_Scopes]
GO


INSERT INTO ScopeTypes (Name,Deactivated)
VALUES ('ClientID',NULL),
('Lender',NULL),
('Condition',NULL),
('Lot', '1/1/2015'),
('State','3/1/2016');

INSERT INTO Scopes
VALUES ('13849EE6-BEA5-428A-BE97-EE80C5BE4D45',1,'123',NULL,NULL),
('A2F5ED8E-C4CA-4E30-9088-7C397C6C060C',1,'234',NULL,NULL),
('D84345BE-94D2-49FB-8E83-7AEFEC9CB0D9',1,'456',NULL,NULL),
('19DF4C40-D677-466A-96B6-B0FC376E081E',2,'Bank of America',NULL,NULL),
('80A6FD36-B175-42D5-9051-A98E211F33F8',2,'Capital One',NULL,NULL),
('4F58920F-7681-41C1-AA86-CFFD2870D7FE',2,'Bank of America','1/1/2015',NULL),
('1B3B0E2D-77E2-4B2D-AC12-DEE32BC22530',3,'New',NULL,NULL),
('14E78F77-7C9D-4598-B906-5F663C31FC01',3,'Pre-Owned',NULL,NULL),
('3C095E25-7C00-45EF-9EC1-2D3A7A1D5220',3,'CPO','1/1/2015',NULL),
('4C4F7971-71CA-4C04-841E-B9FFFC615618',4,'New',NULL,NULL),
('62865A0D-5AD7-488E-A280-A30A09C25217',5,'TX',NULL,NULL),
('A3908E04-C175-40EE-BB55-E39DCA8B0B4A',5,'CA',NULL,NULL),
('F5A785D2-725E-44C5-94EA-B1344696029E',5,'AK','1/1/2015',NULL);

INSERT INTO Stacks
VALUES ('20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5','A Client-Friendly Name',NULL,NULL),
('2CF54F5F-5434-4988-87DB-2AF745538B30','Another Client-Friendly Name',NULL,NULL),
('4F6758AD-32C9-4F7F-A62F-5E852F2F7093','Client-Friendly but Deactivated','1/1/2015',NULL),
('1494EA7F-2601-439E-86BB-C1AF19ACCBE9','lkjdsfohaso fgrawogfhuaw;',NULL,'Not So Friendly')

INSERT INTO StacksScopesMap
VALUES (NEWID(),'20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5','13849EE6-BEA5-428A-BE97-EE80C5BE4D45'), --ClientID
 (NEWID(),'20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5','19DF4C40-D677-466A-96B6-B0FC376E081E'), --Lender
 (NEWID(),'20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5','A3908E04-C175-40EE-BB55-E39DCA8B0B4A'), --State
 (NEWID(),'20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5','4C4F7971-71CA-4C04-841E-B9FFFC615618'), --Lot
 (NEWID(),'20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5','1B3B0E2D-77E2-4B2D-AC12-DEE32BC22530'), --Condition
 (NEWID(),'2CF54F5F-5434-4988-87DB-2AF745538B30','A2F5ED8E-C4CA-4E30-9088-7C397C6C060C'), --ClientID
 (NEWID(),'2CF54F5F-5434-4988-87DB-2AF745538B30','A3908E04-C175-40EE-BB55-E39DCA8B0B4A'), --State
 (NEWID(),'2CF54F5F-5434-4988-87DB-2AF745538B30','14E78F77-7C9D-4598-B906-5F663C31FC01'), --Condition
 (NEWID(),'4F6758AD-32C9-4F7F-A62F-5E852F2F7093','13849EE6-BEA5-428A-BE97-EE80C5BE4D45'), --ClientID
 (NEWID(),'4F6758AD-32C9-4F7F-A62F-5E852F2F7093','4C4F7971-71CA-4C04-841E-B9FFFC615618'), --Lot
 (NEWID(),'20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5','D84345BE-94D2-49FB-8E83-7AEFEC9CB0D9'), --ClientID
 (NEWID(),'20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5','62865A0D-5AD7-488E-A280-A30A09C25217'), --State
 (NEWID(),'20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5','80A6FD36-B175-42D5-9051-A98E211F33F8'), --Lender
 (NEWID(),'1494EA7F-2601-439E-86BB-C1AF19ACCBE9','D84345BE-94D2-49FB-8E83-7AEFEC9CB0D9'), --ClientID
 (NEWID(),'1494EA7F-2601-439E-86BB-C1AF19ACCBE9','62865A0D-5AD7-488E-A280-A30A09C25217'), --State
 (NEWID(),'1494EA7F-2601-439E-86BB-C1AF19ACCBE9','80A6FD36-B175-42D5-9051-A98E211F33F8'); --Lender
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @ClientID   VARCHAR(50) = '123',
        @State      VARCHAR(50) = 'TX',
        @PostalCode VARCHAR(50) = '91210',
        @Lender     VARCHAR(50) = 'Bank of America',
        @Condition  VARCHAR(50) = 'New',
        @Lot        VARCHAR(50) = 'West';

WITH map AS(
SELECT  map.StackId,map.ScopeId,scopes.Scope,types.Name ScopeType,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY map.ScopeId 
                          ORDER BY CASE types.Name
                                        WHEN 'ClientID' THEN 1
                                        WHEN 'State' THEN 2
                                        WHEN 'Postal Code' THEN 3
                                        WHEN 'Lender' THEN 4
                                        WHEN 'Condition' THEN 5
                                        WHEN 'Lot' THEN 6
                                        ELSE 7 END) RN

FROM    StacksScopesMap map
JOIN    Scopes scopes
ON      scopes.ScopeId = map.ScopeId
AND     (scopes.Deactivated IS NULL OR scopes.Deactivated > GETDATE())
JOIN    ScopeTypes types
ON      types.ScopeTypeId = scopes.ScopeTypeId
AND     (types.Deactivated IS NULL OR types.Deactivated > GETDATE())
WHERE   ((types.Name = 'ClientID' AND scopes.Scope = @ClientId) OR @ClientId IS NULL)
OR      ((types.Name = 'Lender' AND scopes.Scope = @Lender) OR @Lender IS NULL)
OR      ((types.Name = 'Condition' AND scopes.Scope = @Condition) OR @Condition IS NULL)
OR      ((types.Name = 'Lot' AND scopes.Scope = @Lot) OR @Lot IS NULL)
OR      ((types.Name = 'State' AND scopes.Scope = @State) OR @State IS NULL)
)
SELECT  *
FROM    map;

WITH map AS(
SELECT  map.StackId,map.ScopeId,scopes.Scope,types.Name ScopeType,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY map.ScopeId 
                          ORDER BY CASE types.Name
                                        WHEN 'ClientID' THEN 1
                                        WHEN 'State' THEN 2
                                        WHEN 'Postal Code' THEN 3
                                        WHEN 'Lender' THEN 4
                                        WHEN 'Condition' THEN 5
                                        WHEN 'Lot' THEN 6
                                        ELSE 7 END) RN

FROM    StacksScopesMap map
JOIN    Scopes scopes
ON      scopes.ScopeId = map.ScopeId
AND     (scopes.Deactivated IS NULL OR scopes.Deactivated > GETDATE())
JOIN    ScopeTypes types
ON      types.ScopeTypeId = scopes.ScopeTypeId
AND     (types.Deactivated IS NULL OR types.Deactivated > GETDATE())
WHERE   ((types.Name = 'ClientID' AND scopes.Scope = @ClientId) OR @ClientId IS NULL)
OR      ((types.Name = 'Lender' AND scopes.Scope = @Lender) OR @Lender IS NULL)
OR      ((types.Name = 'Condition' AND scopes.Scope = @Condition) OR @Condition IS NULL)
OR      ((types.Name = 'Lot' AND scopes.Scope = @Lot) OR @Lot IS NULL)
OR      ((types.Name = 'State' AND scopes.Scope = @State) OR @State IS NULL)
)
SELECT  TOP 1 StackId,COUNT(1) weight
FROM    map
GROUP BY StackId
ORDER BY weight DESC;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01c739/6/0)**:

```
|                              STACKID |                              SCOPEID |           SCOPE | SCOPETYPE | RN |
|--------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|-----------------|-----------|----|
| 20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5 | 62865A0D-5AD7-488E-A280-A30A09C25217 |              TX |     State |  1 |
| 1494EA7F-2601-439E-86BB-C1AF19ACCBE9 | 62865A0D-5AD7-488E-A280-A30A09C25217 |              TX |     State |  2 |
| 20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5 | 19DF4C40-D677-466A-96B6-B0FC376E081E | Bank of America |    Lender |  1 |
| 20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5 | 1B3B0E2D-77E2-4B2D-AC12-DEE32BC22530 |             New | Condition |  1 |
| 20C217E6-F5FC-46DE-83B2-101E59D1D8E5 | 13849EE6-BEA5-428A-BE97-EE80C5BE4D45 |             123 |  ClientID |  1 |
| 4F6758AD-32C9-4F7F-A62F-5E852F2F7093 | 13849EE6-BEA5-428A-BE97-EE80C5BE4D45 |             123 |  ClientID |  2 |
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you're coming from on this, so apologies if you've already done so. But I wanted to point out that it kind of sounds like a Relational Division problem to me. Give this a read and perhaps you can apply it to what you're doing. [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: @sqldriver Thanks! I've never heard of Relational Division in regards to tables before. I'm not sure whether it is applicable to this situation, but it's certainly interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following solution, but I'm still curious if anyone can come up with a better way of ranking these, for future reference.

```
SELECT  TOP 1 StackId,COUNT(1) weight
FROM    StacksScopesMap map
JOIN    Scopes scopes
ON      scopes.ScopeId = map.ScopeId
AND     (scopes.Deactivated IS NULL OR scopes.Deactivated > GETDATE())
JOIN    ScopeTypes types
ON      types.ScopeTypeId = scopes.ScopeTypeId
AND     (types.Deactivated IS NULL OR types.Deactivated > GETDATE())
WHERE   ((types.Name = 'ClientID' AND scopes.Scope = @ClientId) OR @ClientId IS NULL)
OR      ((types.Name = 'Lender' AND scopes.Scope = @Lender) OR @Lender IS NULL)
OR      ((types.Name = 'Condition' AND scopes.Scope = @Condition) OR @Condition IS NULL)
OR      ((types.Name = 'Lot' AND scopes.Scope = @Lot) OR @Lot IS NULL)
OR      ((types.Name = 'State' AND scopes.Scope = @State) OR @State IS NULL)
GROUP BY StackId
ORDER BY weight DESC;
```